# Как можно удалить определенный текст из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

К примеру есть .txt файл, а в нем содержится информация:

```
Просто дом
32
Мяч футбольный
22
Собака сторожевая
```

Каким образом можно удалить определенную строку? Например *мяч футбольный*. А так же сложить *32* и *22*?

Comment: Покажите Вашу попытку решения проблемы.

Comment: Только записать файл заново без нужной строки.

Comment: Код отсутствует, в связи с тем что я додумался до перезаписи в новый файл, по аналогии с массивами, но посчитал этот способ непрактичным из-за "лишних действий" в виде создания нового файла и перезаписи, от того я и обратился на форум. Ведь я только начинающий программист и многого не знаю, может существует какой-то магический способ удаления строки из одного файла без иных телодвижений.

Comment: @smthwrng если файлы небольшие, то ничего страшного, если перезаписывать их целиком. Если же вы работаете с большим файлом, то тут вариант один: считать все что ниже удаляемой строки и вставить все это в файл начиная с начала удаляемой строки (то бишь перезаписать часть файла)

Comment: sed вам в руки!

Comment: Считать целиком текст, поместить его в массив или контейнер с char . Найти в массиве строку "мяч футбольный". Удалить эту строку из массива. Найти два числа, преобразовать char в int, сложить их. Записать это число обратно в массив. В конце все данные из массива записываешь обратно в текстовый документ. Как-то так.

Comment: @smthwrng, никакой магии нет, ваше решение переписать в другой файл (а затем переименовать его в первоначальный) для реальной жизни самое верное (по крайней мере для больших файлов оно самое быстрое)

Comment: Благодарю всех комментаторов за помощь, раньше не мог выразить благодарность в связи с занятостью, прошу прощения) Я выбрал немного иной способ - очистка файла при использовании функцией и перепись с добавлением новой информации, ибо заказчик поставил рамки маленьких файлов